# float makes background disappear

Tags: css, background, css-float

I heard of this problem that float can make your background disappear.
i used this option on 3 divs (that I'm using to make 3 columns).
then gave these divs separate classes.

in the .CSS i put them next to each other like this: .One, .tow, .three
and gave it a float:left;

but now the area where the div is located has no background.
is there a `<tag>` that can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Provide code and more concrete examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "area" does still have it's background image, but since all of it's child element are floating, it has no size.

Add an `overflow: auto;` rule to the CSS for that area and you'll see your background.

Comment: thanks this helped, would you mind answering 1 question. was my question (a bit) confusing, because i got negative point. i thought that this was a problem easy to fix and didn't need showing off codes.

Comment: @user3236466 This pretty much covers it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask